# Weird problem with setTimeout() on Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, settimeout

I searched here and found a quick solution to call an action when the user is idle on the page. It basically works well on all browsers.

But when I use an alert or a confirm dialog on the page, the weird problem occurs on Google Chrome.

After the alert or confirm box disappears (Pressed OK, Cancel or Cross), the idle function works unexpectedly.

- After the box confirm or alert box disappears, which came from the link's onclick, I got '3 seconds passed' box immediately

Tested on FF,IE and Chrome (Latest). It just occurs on Chrome.

My code is here:
http://jsbin.com/ifule3

```
  window.onload = idleTimer;
  function idleTimer() {
    var idleDuration;
    document.onmousemove = idleReset;
    function  idleReset() {
      if (idleDuration) {
        clearTimeout(idleDuration);
        idleDuration = 0;
      }
      idleDuration = setTimeout(function() {
        alert('3 seconds passed.');
      }, 3000)
    }
  };

<a onclick="if(confirm( '?' )) { alert('Ok Pressed.') } else { return false; };">First Link!</a>
<a onclick="alert('test');" >Second Link!</a>
```

It seems my explanation is not enough :/

I changed the code with jQuery;

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var idleDuration;
    jQuery(document).mousemove(function() {
        if (idleDuration) {
            clearTimeout(idleDuration);
            idleDuration = 0;
        }

        idleDuration = setTimeout(function() {
            someIdleAction();
            window.location = 'some url';
        }, 3000)
    })
});
```

When I put this code on my page.It works like a charm.
I open the page, make some mouse actions or not, then 3 seconds without moving mouse, I got the idle alert.This is what I need.

When I put a link that simply calls an alert box and click on it, alert box appears.
Then I close the box and I got the idle alert which is '3 seconds passed'.

```
    <a onclick="if(confirm( 'Are you OK?' )) { alert('Nice.') } else { return false; };">First Link!</a>
    <a onclick="alert('An alert.');" >Second Link!</a>
```

It just occurs on google chrome. With IE and FF everything is fine.
Increasing the timeout, nothing changes.

Comment: *"... the idle function works unexpectedly."* Unexpectedly **how**?!?!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Unlike some other sites, one of the goals is for StackOverflow to *stand alone*. By all means link to handy live examples as you did, but include the code you're using in your question (that's why Yi Jiang copied it there for you). Link rot can set in easily (external resources get removed, renamed, etc.) and besides, people shouldn't have to go elsewhere if they can see what's wrong from the question itself. Have fun!

Comment: @T.J. Crowder, +1 for the, basically, **HULK SMASH!!** =D

Comment: @David: ...Hulk...smash?

Comment: @T.J, the bold-font followed by "!?!?" It amused me for some reason, and I had this vision of an old Hulk comic panel in my head while I giggled. ...this says far more about me than is really appropriate, I suspect... =/

Comment: After the box confirm or alert box disappears, which came from the link's onclick, I got '3 seconds passed' box immediately.

Comment: @egon: Okay, thanks. (You can edit your question to include that info. Click the "edit" link underneath it.)

Comment: @egon, are you saying, if the alert/confirmation box never pops up, the "3 seconds passed" never appear?

Comment: @David: Ah. :-) Then you would have *really* liked my earlier attempt, which I tried to make it both bold *and* italic: But sadly, SO doesn't seem to allow that in comments.

Comment: @T.J., sometimes there just isn't enough punctuation/font-style in the world =)

Comment: I've edited my question.I wish it's more clear now.

Comment: I'm getting the same issue in our application; whenever an `alert` happens, our timers all fire immediately.  Seems like a Chrome bug.

Answer (score 1):

If you're getting the box immediately after dismissing the alert or confirmation, that's not odd, that's normal. `confirm` and `alert` completely stop JavaScript execution. The next call to the timer will queue up waiting for the interpreter to become available again, so dismissing the box bringing up the message doesn't surprise me. Is that the only behavior you're seeing that's a problem?

Comment: The problem is that if you click the second link immediately, and close the alert box immediately, a second alert box will appear, containing "3 seconds passed", even if you did all this in less than 3 seconds...

(Is this comment understandable ?)

Comment: @Crowder - Does IE/FFX suppress the setTimeout "thread" when an alert/confirm box shows up, while Chrome just continues the "thread"? (Excuse my lazyness - Don't have time to verify this on my machine.)

Comment: @Golmote: Yes it is. Nothing changes when you increase the timeout. 3 seconds just for test.

Comment: @DashK: How they implement it is up to them, provided that while the call to `alert` or `confirm` is happening, **no** other JavaScript related to the page runs at all.

Comment: @egon: I get an even weirder result using Chrome for Linux: If I click the first link and press Enter to dismiss the `confirm`, then Enter again to dismiss the `alert`, not only do I immediately get the "3 seconds" alert, but dismissing *that* via the keyboard causes it to show again *instantly*. And this keeps happening as long as I close the alert with the keyboard. If I close the "3 seconds" alert using the mouse instead, that stops the sequence (either immediately, or within a couple of iterations). Does that happen to you?

Comment: @T.J: I can't replicate it. Can you tell me what happens when you click the second link then click OK. If you do it with chrome and ff maybe you can see the difference.

Comment: @egon: It waits until the three seconds have actually passed.

Comment: @T.J: It became weirder now. It doesn't wait on my chrome, even I increase the timeout to 60000. I'll try with chrome for linux.

Comment: @T.J: It works great with chrome and ff on linux as you told. But not works with chrome for windows (7).

Comment: @egon: Well, the *second* link works great. The first is kind of a problem if closing the alert with the keyboard doesn't work. This is very strange... :-)

Comment: If you add a console.log("ideReset", new Date().getTime(); at the beginning of idleReset you can more easily see what is going on.

onmousemove seems to fire the whole time (at least in Chrome and FF - I am a bit surprized, but so it is...). During an alert this does not happen.

There is no difference between the buttons. It is just that it is more likely to take more than 3 seconds to click both of them ... ;-)