# jQuery .css not working only in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

In contradiction to many posts here, my script below works well in Safari and Firefox but not in Chrome. The div "#bg-4-1" is supposed to load with the page at a z-index of -1000 then, when "h3#bubbleh3" is clicked (I know, the naming got out of hand), the z-index shifts to 4.

This works brilliantly everywhere else. I've wrapping the entire thing in `$(window).load(function()` but that doesn't change anything.

Here's the code:

```
        <script>
        $(function() {
            $( "#accordion" ).accordion({
                collapsible: true,
                autoHeight: false,
                active: false
            });
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $(".ui-accordion").bind("accordionchange", function(event, ui) {
                  if ($(ui.newHeader).offset() != null) {
                    ui.newHeader, // $ object, activated header
                    $("html, body").animate({scrollTop: ($(ui.newHeader).offset().top)-0}, 500);
                  }
                });
             });
            $("h3#bubbleh3").on("click", function(event, ui) {   
                setTimeout(function() {            
                    if ($("section#bubble").css("display") === "none") {
                       $("#bg4-1").css("z-index", "-1000");
                    } else if ($("section#bubble").css("display") === "block") {
                       $("#bg4-1").css("z-index", "4");
                    }
                }, 350);
            });
            $("h3#mermaidh3").on("click", function(event, ui) {   
               $("#bg4-1").css("z-index", "-1000");
            });
            $("h3#thingstellh3").on("click", function(event, ui) {   
               $("#bg4-1").css("z-index", "-1000");
            });
            $("h3#sumpartsh3").on("click", function(event, ui) {   
               $("#bg4-1").css("z-index", "-1000");
            });
            $("h3#knivesh3").on("click", function(event, ui) {   
               $("#bg4-1").css("z-index", "-1000");
            });
            $("h3#redgreenh3").on("click", function(event, ui) {   
               $("#bg4-1").css("z-index", "-1000");
            });
            $("h3#resurrecth3").on("click", function(event, ui) {   
               $("#bg4-1").css("z-index", "-1000");
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Thank you for any insight!

Comment: How is `#bg4-1` positioned? Could [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8201970/240443) be the issue?

Comment: `.parallax-bg4 {position: fixed; }
 #bg4-1 {   
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1000;
  }`

where the first div contains the second.

Comment: I'm also trying to add styling inline: `<div id="bg4-1" style="position:absolute;"><iframe id="spotify" src="https://embed.spotify.com/?uri=spotify:user:seedpodpub:playlist:4MsCt5Fkg5G99Tb5VFqzQ4" width="300" height="380" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true"></iframe></div>`

but an unable to get the "hide" portion of the javascript to work in Chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have confirmed that this is the deal here: [z-index not properly rendered on iPad and Google Chrome 22](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12606155/z-index-not-properly-rendered-on-ipad-and-google-chrome-22)

Stacking contexts. In Chrome, "A stacking context is formed, anywhere in the document, by any element which is either

```
the root element (HTML),
positioned (absolutely or relatively) with a z-index value other than "auto",
elements with an opacity value less than 1. (See the specification for opacity)
```

"
In my case, the div#bg4-1 is inside a fixed div so that kills is ability to recede behind the entire page. Bullocks.

Comment: Note that this bug also breaks other css, such as margin-top, top, and who knows what else.  Welcome to Micooglesoft World.  @onomiko Thanks for coming back with that answer.

Answer (score 3):

Yeah thats the same reason of this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8201970/1716774).
Your method has no effect on non-positioned elements, that is, the element must be either absolutely positioned, relatively positioned, or fixed.

```
         <script>
        $(function() {
            $( "#accordion" ).accordion({
                collapsible: true,
                autoHeight: false,
                active: false
            });
            $(document).ready(function() {
                 $("#bg4-1").css("display","none");
                $(".ui-accordion").bind("accordionchange", function(event, ui) {
                  if ($(ui.newHeader).offset() != null) {
                    ui.newHeader, // $ object, activated header
                    $("html, body").animate({scrollTop: ($(ui.newHeader).offset().top)-0}, 500);
                  }
                });
             });
            $("h3#bubbleh3").on("click", function(event, ui)
             {   
                setTimeout(function() {            
                    if ($("section#bubble").css("display") === "none") {

                       $("#bg4-1").css("z-index", "-1000");
                       $("#bg4-1").css("display","none");
                    } else if ($("section#bubble").css("display") === "block") {
                         $("#bg4-1").css("display","block");
                       $("#bg4-1").css("z-index", "4");
                    }
                }, 350);
            });
            $("h3#mermaidh3").on("click", function(event, ui) {   
               $("#bg4-1").css("z-index", "-1000");
            });
            $("h3#thingstellh3").on("click", function(event, ui) {   
               $("#bg4-1").css("z-index", "-1000");
            });
            $("h3#sumpartsh3").on("click", function(event, ui) {   
               $("#bg4-1").css("z-index", "-1000");
            });
            $("h3#knivesh3").on("click", function(event, ui) {   
               $("#bg4-1").css("z-index", "-1000");
            });
            $("h3#redgreenh3").on("click", function(event, ui) {   
               $("#bg4-1").css("z-index", "-1000");
            });
            $("h3#resurrecth3").on("click", function(event, ui) {   
               $("#bg4-1").css("z-index", "-1000");
            });
        });
```

Just change these lines its working fine in my chrome check it out. You can refer [My blog](http://vivekdragon.wordpress.com/) to know more about these problems. i am writing an article in it

Comment: Thank you Vivek and thank you for writing out the solution as I would have been working out where to place what for a while.

Question: #bg4-1 is absolutely positioned within a fixed div via the css. I tried your solution without altering the css but nothing changed. I then removed the absolute positioning in the css and got partial results (the div was hidden on load but wouldn't return to being hidden). Thoughts?

Comment: And thank you for the link. I'd somehow missed that one in all the research.

Comment: Did you have any thoughts on why it isn't working based on the extra info I've added here? (I hope)

Comment: I am glad to help post your code in a [JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/) and i will look at it

Comment: ...I wasn't sure what else to do with that jsbin site so I pasted all my code in there. I'm sure that's overkill. Can you see it here? http://jsbin.com/eyesiq/1/edit

It works fine, except in Chrome. Look for the Spotify playlist that appears when you click "The Bubble Creatures". Otherwise, the important bits are here on this SO thread. Thanks again. This is kind of you to take the time.

Comment: @ i am working on your bin which section i have to look into? Do you need to load that Spotify playlist  inside your page?

Comment: I'm wanting to show the playlist when "The Bubble Creatures" h3 is clicked and hide all other times. I did it this way because the iframe wasn't loading inside the accordion and show/hide didn't work.

Comment: Dude the problem is setTimeout() is not working in chrome :)    http://stackoverflow.com/a/3787240/1716774

Comment: Thanks for trying. No change for me in Chrome (cache cleared). The Spotify appears on load and just sits there. I'll keep learning from what you've offered though. I appreciate it.

Comment: Oh i forgot to place a line in it :) check now